# GridGain.start(GridConfiguration cfg, org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext springCtx) missing in the newer version

Tags: gridgain

I was using 6.1.1 and 
GridGain.start(GridConfiguration cfg, org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext springCtx). But it seems in the newer version, for example 6.1.9, that API is missing.

what is the replacement for that API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This API became a part of `gridgain-spring` module and is now on `GridGainSpring` class. Such refactoring was performed to make sure that `gridgain-core` module has zero dependencies.